# an instance of type 'android.view.ViewGroup' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'com.android.keyguard.ChallengeLayout'

Tags: java, android

How to fix this error

> an instance of type 'android.view.ViewGroup' cannot be assigned to a
>   variable of type `com.android.keyguard.ChallengeLayout`

Code

```
ChallengeLayout challenge = mSlidingChallengeLayout != null ? 
mSlidingChallengeLayout : mMultiPaneChallengeLayout;
```

Comment: Could you show us where `mSlidingChallengeLayout` and `mMultiPaneChallengeLayout` are defined? And what is `ChallengeLayout`? Please do so [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52406321/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mean that your layout is not king of `ViewGroup`. 
The interface `[ChallengeLayout][1]` is to be implemented by your ViewGroup, here ,it seems to be `SlidingChallengeLayout`...  So make sure that the class `SlidingChallengeLayout` implements `ChallengeLayout`

PS: the ChallengeLayout is not public API. Make sure that you really need it for a custom Android ROM...

Comment: SlidingChallengeLayout is already implemented ChallengeLayout 

Comment: could you post complete stacktrace and the code for mMultiPaneChallengeLayout and  mSlidingChallengeLayout? I think that there is an issue with your imports...

Comment: Check it out https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/packages/Keyguard/src/com/android/keyguard/KeyguardHostView.java